# Automatically forward one socket to another

Tags: c, sockets, unix, network-programming, posix

I have two file descriptors created with `socket()` and both are connected to separate hosts. I want anything received on the first socket to be immediately sent on the second and vice versa.

I know can achieve this manually with a combination of `select()`, `send()` and `recv()`, but is there a more direct way to tell the kernel to simply pipe the output from one into the other?

Comment: You could probably do it using an iptables rule. This would execute in kernel space. My iptables is rusty so I can't fill in the details..

Comment: On recent lines, there's `splice()` which is pretty much exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can use a tool like `netcat` which does this for you (so you don't have to write the code) but even `netcat` contains a loop that copies the data.